# How to add existing UI to SWT Designer (WindowBuilder)

Tags: eclipse, swt, windowbuilder

I have a project with many ui components (Groups and Composites) that I created manually, so I want to add/see them in SWT Designer. 
Where are these classes assigned to WindowBuilder? 
For example if I create a composite from the eclipse New -> composite then I can see the UI in the designer, but weather I copy this composite class then the copy is not visualised in the Designer, so I think a register or configuration should exist somewhere but I cannot figure it out.

```
public class Plc extends Group {

    public Plc(Composite parent, int style) {
        super(parent, style);
    }

   @Override
    protected void checkSubclass() {        
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not supposed to subclass `Group` so it probably doesn't support this.

Comment: This is the way that WindowBuilder does it, I am just copying an example.